# How to make pre-receive hook ignore commits already submitted

Tags: git, hook

I have a pre-receive hook to validate the commit message, to check if it has a valid JIRA issue on the beggining.

But I have some old commits that does not fit my pattern (they were made long time ago)

Example:

```
  A--B--C--D--E--F
  ^              ^
  |              | 
  |              |_ HEAD
origin/master
```

A: That is where my origin/master points to

A, B, C and D: The commits that does not contain a valid commit message (and they should not, they are really old)

E and F: They are ok, with valid message.

When I try to run:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

It would be just a fast-forward (All the commits are already on remote repository)

I would like to make my pre-receive script 'detect' it, and did not try to validade the message for commits A, B, C, D, E and F.

My pre-receive script receives 3 paramaters: 'A', 'F' and 'refs/heads/master'

My pre-receive script is running:

```
git rev-list A..F
```

That will return a list of commits between A and F, and I will iterate one by one.

Thanks.

Comment: Since those are first 6 commits, you can use counter that you will increase on each iteration. If the counter is less than 6 skip the validation of the commit message.

Comment: Antoan, but what if I have a next commit (like call it 'G'), and it is a fresh-new commit? 
In this case, I will need to skip the validation for first 6 (A to F) but I will need to validate the G. How do I known that first 6 are already on remote repository, and the new one (G) is just being pushed now for the first time? My parameters in this case will be 'A', 'G', and 'refs/heads/master'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git log --after=<date>` and filter based on the date and the message text.
Every commit after some date should have Jira issue number.

Comment: Very good idea! I tested using the '--after' parameter for git rev-list command, and it worked! I think it is better than use 'git log', because I would need to run this 'git log' command for each commit the 'rev-list' returns. Adding the --after on rev-list command, it will return just what I need and it is more efficient! :)
Tks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why not test the reachability of the commit with something like `git branch --contains`, and only process it if it isn't reachable via some other ref ?

```
   alreadyPresent=$(git branch --contains ${commit} | wc -l)
   if [ ${alreadyPresent} -ne 0 ]
   then 
      echo "${commit} already processed"
   else
      echo "${commit} needs processing"

   fi
```

Comment: It will probably work, but I have some cases that more then 200 commits are being returned from 'rev-list' and run another git command for each one (git branch) will make the push process slow. I tried the '--after=<date>'as parameter for git rev-list, as suggested by @antoan-milkov, and it worked! Tks, anyway :)

Comment: If the date thing works for you go with that.  I've been burned by dates so many times I never use them.  All it takes is one person with a whacky date setting and they can create a commit from 10 years ago and then nothing works.